# Improve performance by combining two quieries

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-performance

I have following submission table. A submission is an image.

```
create table submission
(
    md5 varchar(255) not null
        constraint submission_pkey
            primary key,
    user_name varchar(255)
        constraint fkmc6ld10rt5dgfsypoanfxifaj
            references users,
    copy_of varchar(255),
    create_date timestamp
);
```

`copy_of` is the submission_pkey (md5) of another user who has posted the same submission (image).
In other words if two users post the same image the later submission will contain an `copy_of` to the submission_pkey of the first image.

Now I am looking for a query which given one `user_name` will return a set of other usernames who have posted the same submission.
In this list I also want the usernames which the current `user_name` has copied the submissions from.

For this I have created two queries which together return the desired result set:

First:

```
select (select name
        from users
                 inner join submission s2 on users.name = s2.user_name
        where s2.md5 = s.copy_of) as other
from users
         inner join submission s on users.name = s.user_name
where copy_of is not null
  and name = ?1
group by name, other;
```

Second:

```
select (select user_name from submission where copy_of = s.md5 limit 1)
from users
         inner join submission s on users.name = s.user_name
where name = ?1
  and md5 in (select copy_of from submission s2);
```

Both (especially the second) queries run quite slow. Is there a way to improve those queries and ideally combine them to return one distinct list of `user_name`? I feel like the join with the users table should not be needed since all the relevant data is in the submission table but I have not found a way without it.

Comment: You can combine queries with UNION or UNION ALL, but I wouldn't expect that to improve the performance.  For performance questions, please include EXPLAIN ANALYZE.

Comment: Why the limit 1?  Is that just to avoid errors, or do you actually want to limit it that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can it be?

```sql
select distinct s2.user_name 
from submission s1
  join submission s2 
    on s1.md5 = s2.copy_of 
    or s1.copy_of = s2.copy_of 
    or s1.copy_of = s2.md5
where s1.user_name = ?1 
 and s2.copy_of is not null;
```

`s1.md5 = s2.copy_of` will match submission which is copy from this user.
`s1.copy_of = s2.copy_of or s1.copy_of = s2.md5` will match submission which current user copy from.

Comment: Beautiful! That did it and much faster than any other solution I came up with

Answer (score 1):

I would use a self-join

```
select u1.name, string_agg(s2.user_name, ',') as other users
from users u1
   join submission s1 on u1.name = s1.user_name
   join submission s2 on s1.md5 = s2.copy_of
where name = ?1
group by u1.name;
```

Comment: This does not cover the first query that looks at other from which the current user has copied submissions from. It covers the second query looking for users who have copied submission from the current user.